# Game Theory - n-player friends/enemies game

Tags: game-theory

"Consider the following game with n players $\{1, . . . , n\}$. Each player is invited to two parties.
All players like to party, but the parties are on the same day, so each player has to decide
which of the two parties to attend.
Some of the players are enemies. The set of enemies of player i is denoted by $E_i ⊆ \{1, . . . , n\}$.
If player $j$ is an enemy of player $i$, player $i$ is also an enemy of player $j$, that is,
$j \in E_i \iff i \in E_j$.

Each player wants to minimize the number of enemies that attend the same party as they do.
In other words, if $L$ of player $i$’s enemies attend the same party as player $i$, player $i$’s payoff is $−L$."

I'm trying to argue that the game has a pure Nash equilibrium. However, I'm having trouble understanding how the addition of new players, who may have enemies already present at one or both of the parties, can be done without disrupting the choices of those players who've already gone to one of the parties.

Comment: Are there only two parties? That is, all of the players are invited to the same parties? Also, do they know who *other* players have as enemies? Because that seems pretty important for determining a strategy.

Comment: There are only two parties to which a player can be invited. I think we assume that they know all information about both their enemies and other players' enemies.

Comment: Okay, I have another question. Why is it problem if adding players "disrupts" the other players' choices? Doesn't adding more players make it a different game, so different equilibrium strategies are to be expected?

Comment: I thought that a way to prove the existence of a Nash equilibrium might be to compute it by iteratively including players into one of two parties and showing that they will be happy with their choice, but I wasn't taking into account that their choice might cause previous players to have chosen incorrectly.

Comment: Basically I was showing that it's POSSIBLE for a player to be happy with their choice of party, rather than showing that a pure Nash equilibrium exists when ALL players are happy with their choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof that the game has a Nash equilibrium in pure strategies. Suppose we pick an allocation of players to parties that minimizes the total number of enemies at the same party. Such an allocation must exist because the number of possible allocations is finite. Such an allocation will be a Nash equilibrium. If a player could switch from one party to another because he/she has fewer enemies at the other party, then such a switch would also reduce the total number of enemies at the same party. Therefore, if there was such a deviation, that would contradict the assumption that we have picked an allocation of players to parties that minimizes the number of enemies at the same party.

Comment: This makes sense to me. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know where I can find more information about this class of games? I've been looking at coalition formation, but it doesn't seem to be quite the same thing

Comment: I can't think of an interesting class of games to which this one belongs, except that it is a game with a potential function (the total number of enemies at the same party is a potential function for this game). This class of games was defined in: Monderer and Shapley: "Potential Games", Games and Economic Behavior 14, pp. 124–143 (1996). My "proof" makes use of the potential function, and is a standard argument for games with a potential function. But having a potential function is more a mathematical feature of the game than one that has to do with the interpretation of the game.